# My 18 month old daughter too much sweating during sleep time and it leads a sleep problem

Tags: sleep, parents, sleep-training, naps

My daughter is 18 months old, and she sweats when she sleeps especially during night time. I think because of the issue and hotness, she often wakes up at midnight. It is frustrating for me, but I also worry that the short time sleeping and often waking up during night might affect badly her development... Does this something happen to other babies or kids as well, and any solutions or recommendations? 
I put her 100% cotton half sleeve PJ.  I appreciate any kind of comments here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that waking up during the night is probably not doing her any harm as long as her total sleep amount is enough for her needs.  My son is almost 3 and has never slept through the night, yet is meeting all his milestones handily.  Many toddlers and young children experience night waking with no ill effects.

Sweaty sleeping seems to be pretty common with kids and babies, and many of them don't seem bothered by it.  If the problem seems truly severe, you may want to ask her doctor, as excessive sweating (all the time, not just when sleeping) can be a sign of hyperthyroid or other treatable issues.

If you think that heat and discomfort are her problem you can try one or a few of the following, and see if any of them help.

Use a fan (or if you have the heat on, set the thermostat a bit lower)

Use breathable bedding.  Some microfiber or synthetic sheets, plastic mattress protectors and similar products are not at all breathable and can contribute to the 'sweaty hotness'.  You can buy specific 'cooling' mattress toppers and bedding, or just try to put more breathable cotton layers between her and the plastic/unbreathable layer.

Let her sleep in just diaper/underpants and a chemise, or otherwise fewer clothes.

Here's some more info about sweating in babies:
https://www.healthline.com/health/baby/sweaty-baby